# java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:433)

Tags: solr, lucene

Getting the below exception while search from solr.Please help me find the issue

error":{
"trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:433)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser.parseTerm(ValueSourceParser.java:998)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser.access$100(ValueSourceParser.java:83)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser$61.parse(ValueSourceParser.java:675)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.FunctionQParser.parseValueSource(FunctionQParser.java:368)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.FunctionQParser.parseValueSource(FunctionQParser.java:235)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser$73.parse(ValueSourceParser.java:822)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.FunctionQParser.parseValueSource(FunctionQParser.java:368)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.FunctionQParser.parse(FunctionQParser.java:80)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:168)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrReturnFields.add(SolrReturnFields.java:302)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrReturnFields.parseFieldList(SolrReturnFields.java:114)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrReturnFields.(SolrReturnFields.java:100)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrReturnFields.(SolrReturnFields.java:76)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:269)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2440)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:347)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:298)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n",

Comment: how are you indexing the data? using solr api?

Comment: Indexing is done using spring batch using solrclient.

Comment: you must not be passing any value which is mandatory at the solr side...defined as required=true in schema.xml

Comment: and sharing the stacktrace is of no use...you need to share the piece of code which is causing the error